# Insert functions inserts an empty record into database table in ABAP SAP

Tags: abap, opensql

Basically I'm trying to insert a record from a form  into a database table. Not sure why it adds in empty record.

```
Here's my codes:
*--------------Screen 9003------------------------------------------------------------*

MODULE status_9003 OUTPUT.
  SET PF-STATUS 'PF_PO_INN'.
  SET TITLEBAR 'PO_TITLE1'.

ENDMODULE.


module user_command_9003 input.

  "IF sy-ucomm = 'EXE'.
  IF sy-ucomm = 'CREATE'.
    PERFORM ADD_COURSE.
  ELSEIF SY-UCOMM = 'BACK'.
    PERFORM CLEAR_INPUTS.
    LEAVE TO SCREEN 9001.
  ENDIF.
ENDMODULE.
*-------------------Create course--------------------------------------*
FORM ADD_COURSE.
  DATA  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD LIKE TABLE OF ZCMS_COURSES WITH HEADER LINE.

  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_ID = ZCMS_COURSES-COURSE_ID.
  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_CONTENT = ZCMS_COURSES-COURSE_CONTENT .
  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-MUSIC_GENRE = ZCMS_COURSES-MUSIC_GENRE.
  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-OPTIONS = ZCMS_COURSES-OPTIONS.
  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_NAME = ZCMS_COURSES-COURSE_NAME.


  INSERT ZCMS_COURSES FROM ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD.

  MODIFY zcms_courses FROM TABLE ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD.

  SELECT * INTO TABLE  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD FROM zcms_courses.

  LOOP AT ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD.
    WRITE AT: /1(2) sy-tabix,
    6   ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_NAME,
    20  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_CONTENT,
    30  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-OPTIONS,
    46  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-MUSIC_GENRE.
  ENDLOOP.


  "To show that record is added
  MESSAGE 'Course Created.' TYPE 'S'.
ENDFORM.
```

[image]

It inserts an empty record as shown above

[image]

^User input record is added into the database as "Course Created" message pops up.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint at the INSERT and see if it is executed 2 times. Then put the BP before to determine what is provoking the second excecution

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do with your code. The `MODIFY` commands make no sense, the internal table will always be empty. I do not see how this code can generate an empty record, maybe it was in the table before?

Comment: I think something is triggering the even before the information is ready.I had the same problem some time ago. It was something with the ALV events.

Answer (score 3):

You did not append the values to the internal table. And also, you do not need an insert statement, if you are using modify statement. Modify will update if there are records with that key fields, if not it will insert.

it should be like:

```
*-------------------Create course--------------------------------------*
FORM ADD_COURSE.
  DATA  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD LIKE TABLE OF ZCMS_COURSES WITH HEADER LINE.
  " filling the header(work area) of the itab
  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_ID = ZCMS_COURSES-COURSE_ID.
  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_CONTENT = ZCMS_COURSES-COURSE_CONTENT .
  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-MUSIC_GENRE = ZCMS_COURSES-MUSIC_GENRE.
  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-OPTIONS = ZCMS_COURSES-OPTIONS.
  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_NAME = ZCMS_COURSES-COURSE_NAME.
  " Now you filled the itab.
  APPEND ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD. 

  " You don't need insert statement modify will update/insert operations. 
  "INSERT ZCMS_COURSES FROM ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD.

  MODIFY zcms_courses FROM TABLE ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD.

  SELECT * INTO TABLE  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD FROM zcms_courses.

  LOOP AT ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD.
    WRITE AT: /1(2) sy-tabix,
    6   ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_NAME,
    20  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-COURSE_CONTENT,
    30  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-OPTIONS,
    46  ITAB_ZCMS_COURSES_HD-MUSIC_GENRE.
  ENDLOOP.


  "To show that record is added
  MESSAGE 'Course Created.' TYPE 'S'.
ENDFORM.
```